# Not able to add percentage labels with two decimals in ggplot2 geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add the column `values` as geom text with ggplot2:

```
df <- structure(list(type = structure(1:4, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d"), class = "factor"), values = c(0.166667, 0.416667, 0.083333, 
0.333333)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Input:

```
round(df$values, digits = 4)
```

Out:

```
[1] 0.1667 0.4167 0.0833 0.3333
```

Input:

```
scales::percent(round(df$values, digits = 4))
```

Out:

```
[1] "16.7%" "41.7%" "8.3%"  "33.3%"
```

As you can notice, the result only round to one decimals percentage values, but I need two decimals.

This line of code is for adding text for the plot:

```
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(round(df$values, digits = 4))), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

How could I modify the paramters above to round them correctly? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried: `scales::percent(round(df$values, digits = 4)), accuracy = 0.01)`?

Comment: Updated the `df`, please check @Edo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `accuracy` with the `scales::percent()` function:

```
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(round(df$values, digits = 4), accuracy = 0.01)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

from documentation the correct code seems to be:

```
scales::percent(df$values, accuracy = 0.01)
```

Comment: It raises an error: `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label`, with `geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(df$values, accuracy = 0.01)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`